# Humio/LogScale equivalent for Splunk's multikv comand

Tags: splunk, humio

What is the Humio / LogScale equivalent for Splunk [multikv](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Multikv) command? I currently extract it with a complex regex extraction with repeat=True.